# How to export into excel from php leading with zeroes

Tags: php, excel

Here's my code of export. Just want to lead with zeroes because that's my unique code of every students but after I export into excel the zeroes are gone. What am I suppose to do.

```
  function db_connect(){
include('dbcon.php');
if ($dbcon->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $dbcon->connect_error);
}
  return $dbcon;
 }

 $filename ="Users.xls";
 header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM member";
 $dbcon = db_connect();
 if($dbcon){
$result = $dbcon->query($sql);
echo "User ID\tFNAME\tLNAME\tTYPE\tCOURSE\tYEAR LEVEL\tCODE\n"; // prints header line with field names
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['stud_num']."\t".$row['firstname']."\t".$row['lastname']."\t". $row['type']."\t".$row['course']."\t".$row['year_level']."\t".$row['code']."\n";// prints each record with five fields in a row
            }
    } 
}
```

[image: Export excel]  [image: Zeroes] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT19L.jpg

Comment: Prepending a single quote should work.

Comment: @TimWilliams what will I change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will input an all numeric field as an int and drop your left 0's. To trick Excels importer to see it as a text field, you need to format it like a simple forumula.  In your echo line, change

```
."\t".$row['code']."\n"
```

to

```
."\t\"=\"\"".$row['code']."\"\"\"\n"
```

Cut n paste that directly in and see if that gives you the results you want.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lIs2O , no change at all hmm the str pad left didn't change color it seems it's not working? or working? btw thank you

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by didnt change color.  Do you mean in your IDE it didnt change color? It probably wouldnt since it is a flag.  But when you did add the str_pad() item, what were the results in the Excel Export?

Comment: I mean yes it didn't change color. but in the results is same nothing change. I tried input " ' "  after ."\t".but If I import it will \'00000000

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  Your data is coming out of your database with the 0's already because it is varchar and not an int as I assumed.  The problem is that Excel when opening a comma delimited file, which is what this is, will always assume that a field with just numbers will be an int field and will drop the 0's.  The only way around this with the approach you are taking is to put a non-numeric character in front.  I dont know just how you are using  your excel, but one approach could be to put a # sign in front, so instead of seeing 0000536047, it would be #0000536047.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Because if there's an export then it has import too, so What if I import it? I don't think it will accept when it's have # in front of code. What will I do?

Comment: Ok, I have come up with a workaround for you to trick Excel's importer to see it as a text field.  I have modified my answer to relfect this.  Try it and see how it works for you.